# Managing static files for multiple apps in Django

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I am developing a Django (1.3) project composed of many applications. Each application has its own static files under its own `static` directory. Moreover, I have added a directory called `project_static` which should contain static files which are common throughout the various applications, such as jQuery.

The problem I immediately run into is that of naming collisions. By default, `collectstatic` will just put everything under a global `static` directory, without classifying them  by application. This does not work for me, as each application has - for instance - a file called `css/screen.css`.

The way I solved it is by removing `django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder` from `STATICFILES_FINDERS` and using [namespaced static files dirs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#prefixes-optional), so my settings now look like:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'project_static'),
    ('my_app', os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'my_app', 'static')),
    ('another_app', os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'another_app', 'static')),
    ...
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
)
```

The problem is that in this way I lose the static files for all other applications (e.g. `django.contrib.admin`). Of course I could manually add the admin, but I'm not sure how to do this without breaking the admin, which has a different directory structure.

> Is there a better way to manage the static files with more than one application?

Answer (score 57):

This is the same problem that occurs with using app-specific `templates` directories. If you just throw the files directly under `templates` in the app, you'll end up with name collisions if two apps or even the project-level `templates` directory utilize templates of the same name. The fix for that is to actually put the templates in a directory of the name of app inside the `templates` directory like:

```
- some_app
    - templates
        - some_app
            - index.html
```

So, I apply the same idea to static:

```
- some_app
    - static
        - some_app
            - css
            - img
            - js
```

That way, when you run collectstatic, each individual app's static files get placed inside a namespaced directory. The only change you need to make is to prefix each of the files with the app-name directory in your templates. So instead of `{{ STATIC_URL }}css/style.css` you have `{{ STATIC_URL }}my_app/css/style.css`.

Comment: if we serve the static files using nginx is this still the preferred way? (keeping static files, templates in the app itself)

Comment: Not great for portability but probably the best simple solution